# AWS VPC and Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, aws

I am trying to setup a VPN connection using AWS VPC. I have generated the VPN configuration files and have sent to the client. However the client is asking for the Blue highlighted info in the attached image. I'm wondering where can I get these info.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your Third party VPN device should be the AWS Managed VPN, to get more information use the AWS CLI to interrogate the VPN Gateway see link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html

Also the question regarding the "redirect to" concerns the subnets on the VPC side, where after the VPC "Routing Table" you will have a "NAT Gateway" to translate the customer network into the private IP range used in the VPC.

See link on NAT gateways and VPC.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html